# Firebase functions - HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm running into a strange issue.

I'm trying to use 2 `wildcards` and I keep getting an error saying:

> !  functions: failed to create function modRemoveReplies
>
> HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors

The interesting thing is that I have another `export` that uses almost the same wildcards but doesn't produce an error...

This is the code where I get an error:

```
exports.modRemoveReplies = functions.database
  .ref('replies/{parent}/{postId}/flag_delete')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    console.log("Test")
    return true;
});
```

but earlier in my functions file I call this code with absolute **no errors**:

```
exports.removeReply = functions.database
  .ref('replies/{parent}/{postId}/score')
  .onUpdate(async change => {
    const score = change.after.val();
    if (score === -4) {
      return change.after.ref.parent.remove();
    }
  });
```

It's practically identical so I understand why 'd be getting that error... Any ideas? The error message above is the only information that gets displayed.

**Edit:**

After running with the `--debug` flag this was the output:

> [2019-05-30T20:55:47.156Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 400 vary=X-Origin,
> Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, content-type=application/json;
> charset=UTF-8, date=Thu, 30 May 2019 20:55:43 GMT, server=ESF,
> cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN,
> x-content-type-options=nosniff, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000;
> v="46,44,43,39", accept-ranges=none, connection=close
>
> [2019-05-30T20:55:47.156Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY code=400,
> message=The request has errors, status=INVALID_ARGUMENT,
> details=[@type=type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest,
> fieldViolations=[field=runtime, description=Runtime field cannot be
> empty.]]

Comment: Run the command with `--debug` and edit the question to show what it's saying.  If the output isn't helpful, you might have to contact Firebase support.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, I edited the question to include the information from the `--debug` flag

Comment: Make sure your CLI is fully up to date, try again, and contact Firebase support directly if you still have problems.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, I figured it out and answered my own question :)

Comment: For me running "npm install -g firebase-tools" solved the problem

Comment: @simon – how did you figure it out?

Comment: @ChrisCurnow I don't remember the exact steps but I had to update firebase functions to the latest version. After updating it fixed all my issues. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this issue because my path was incorrect. I had it like this:

```
functions.firestore
.document('/companies/{companyID}/tickets/')
  .onCreate((change, context) => { 

  // code here.

  })
```

Instead of:

```
functions.firestore
.document('/companies/{companyID}/tickets')
  .onCreate((change, context) => { 

  // code here.

  })
```

Note the slash at the end of the path.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to change

```
export const onRatingCreated = functions.firestore.document('Programs/{programId}/Ratings/').onCreate((doc, context) => {
    // ...
});
```

To this

```
export const onRatingCreated = functions.firestore.document('Programs/{programId}/Ratings/{ratingId}').onCreate((doc, context) => {
    // ...
});
```

So, ending with a Document wildcard fixed it for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Intuitively, since it's the `document` function, the last element in the path-like expression should be a document.